# Quickbook PHP SDK with yii1.1.14 integration error

Tags: php, yii, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am getting below error, while using quickbook online PHP sdk integration. Now I am trying to call the companyInfo API through the below sample code. But every time I stuck with the error "include(string.php)" not found. Any quick help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
$dataService = new DataService($this->serviceContext);
if (!$dataService)
    exit("Problem while initializing DataService.\n");

$allCompanies = $dataService->FindAll('CompanyInfo');
```

Here is my error page screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue by modifying the code as below and make it compatible to run with yii1.X

Modify in the below path in sdk library
XSD2PHP/src/com/mikebevz/xsd2php/Bind.php

```
(!class_exists(class_name)($className))
```

to

```
!(class_exists(class_name)($className,false))
```